# As if multiple window application JFrame Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have recently started learning Java and creating gui program using JFrame. I wanted to do something like pressing a button so that everything that is currently in the window disappears (JButton and JLabel) and that it shows the other buttons so that everything is still in one window. My code looks like this:

```
package gui;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

import app.Exit;
import app.Logger;

public class MainMenu extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

    // Create objects
    public static Logger log = new Logger();

    // Buttons declaration
    JButton bExit, bStartBot, bOptions, bAboutLikeplusBot, bChangelog;

    // Label declaration
    JLabel lLogo;

    public MainMenu() throws IOException {

        // Set window size
        log.AddToLog("Set window size", "JFrame", "INFO");
        setSize(800, 500);

        // Disable window resizable
        log.AddToLog("Disable window resizable", "JFrame", "INFO");
        setResizable(false);

        // Set window title
        log.AddToLog("Set window title", "JFrame", "INFO");
        setTitle("LikeplusBot");

        // Set layout
        log.AddToLog("Set layout", "JFrame", "INFO");
        setLayout(null);

        // Add Exit button
        log.AddToLog("Add Exit button", "JFrame/JButton", "INFO");
        bExit = new JButton("Exit");
        bExit.setBounds(610, 365, 160, 70);
        add(bExit);
        bExit.addActionListener(this);

        // Add Start bot button
        log.AddToLog("Add Start bot button", "JFrame/JButton", "INFO");
        bStartBot = new JButton("Start bot");
        bStartBot.setBounds(610, 25, 160, 70);
        add(bStartBot);
        bStartBot.addActionListener(this);

        // Add Options button
        log.AddToLog("Add Options button", "JFrame/JButton", "INFO");
        bOptions = new JButton("Options");
        bOptions.setBounds(610, 110, 160, 70);
        add(bOptions);
        bOptions.addActionListener(this);

        // Add About LikeplusBot button
        log.AddToLog("Add About LikeplusBot button", "JFrame/JButton", "INFO");
        bAboutLikeplusBot = new JButton("About LikeplusBot");
        bAboutLikeplusBot.setBounds(610, 195, 160, 70);
        add(bAboutLikeplusBot);
        bAboutLikeplusBot.addActionListener(this);

        // THIS IS A BUTTON WHICH A PRESS IS TO BE DISPLAYED BY OTHER BUTTONS ---------------------------
        // Add Changelog button
        log.AddToLog("Add Changelog button", "JFrame/JButton", "INFO");
        bChangelog = new JButton("Changelog");
        bChangelog.setBounds(610, 280, 160, 70);
        add(bChangelog);
        bChangelog.addActionListener(this);

        // Add logo photo
        log.AddToLog("Add logo photo", "JFrame/JLabel", "INFO");
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(MainMenu.class.getResource("/resources/LPB_300x300.png"));
        lLogo = new JLabel();
        lLogo.setBounds(120, 20, 400, 400);
        lLogo.setIcon(icon);
        add(lLogo);

    }

    /*
     * Show window
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        // Create object
        MainMenu window = new MainMenu();

        // Chose default close operation
        log.AddToLog("Set default close operation", "JFrame", "INFO");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Set window visible
        log.AddToLog("Set window visible", "JFrame", "INFO");
        window.setVisible(true);

        // Set window icon
        log.AddToLog("Set window icon", "JFrame", "INFO");
        ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(MainMenu.class.getResource("/resources/WindowIcon_32x32.png"));
        window.setIconImage(img.getImage());

    }

    /*
     * What is to be done after pressing the button
     */
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        Object source = e.getSource();

        // Exit button
        if (source==bExit) {

            try {
                log.AddToLog("Exit button clicked", "ActionListener", "INFO");
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
            Exit exit = new Exit();
            try {
                exit.Exit();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        // Start bot button
        if (source==bStartBot) {

            try {
                log.AddToLog("Start bot button clicked", "ActionListener", "INFO");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        // Options button
        if (source==bOptions) {

            try {
                log.AddToLog("Options button clicked", "ActionListener", "INFO");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        // About LikeplusBot button
        if (source==bAboutLikeplusBot) {

            try {
                log.AddToLog("About LikeplusBot button clicked", "ActionListener", "INFO");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        // THIS IS PERFORMED AFTER THIS BUTTON IS PRESSED ----------------------------------------------
        // Changelog button
        if (source==bChangelog) {

            try {
                log.AddToLog("Changelog button clicked", "ActionListener", "INFO");
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            Changelog changelog = new Changelog();

            // AND I WANT THIS METHOD THAT IS CALLED HERE SHOWING NEW BUTTONS IN THE WINDOW -------------
            try {
                changelog.Changelog();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I hope you can understand something :)

Comment: In the actionPerformed() method under the appropriate button is where you'd put your hide/show logic.  You can use .setVisible(false) method to hide the various JComponents.

Comment: Ok, I added there https://pastebin.com/LJftKnJk And it works, but when I create a new button in this method what it calls or Changelog() then nothing will be displayed, and the point is that it would create new buttons in this method.

Comment: Not really sure what you're trying to say, but you don't want to keep creating and hiding buttons. That's wasteful memory. Unhide the existing buttons, or if you don't need them ever again and need different components then delete instead of hiding.

Comment: Ok a więc teraz to wygląda tak https://pastebin.com/mj5b6Pat jak zamieniłem ukrywanie na usuwanie. Próbuje osiągnąć to że gdy nacisne przycisk bChangelog to usunie wszystkie przyciski które teraz są i wywoła metode Changelog() która utworzy nowe inne przyciski.

Comment: 1) *so that everything that is currently in the window disappears (JButton and JLabel) and that it shows the other buttons so that everything is still in one window.* Use a [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html). A `CardLayout` allows you to swap panels. 2) method names should NOT start with an upper case character.

Comment: And you can't do it that removes the previous buttons and calls the changelog() method which adds new ones?

Answer (score 0):

You should use setVisible(false) for the components you want to hide, and setVisible(true) for the components you want to show.
Probably you need to add  a boolean parameter on your changeLog method. And do hide or show things according to parameter